# AngularFire how to remove multiple items from array?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using Firebase and the AngularFire library.  I am looking for a way to remove all items or a range of items from a $firebaseArray object.  I don't see a straightforward way to do it in the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-save).  Is there some way I'm not thinking of other than looping and removing items one by one?  Please tell me that's not the only way!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a method in the [`$firebaseArray`](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebasearray) that does what you want, you can use the array's `$ref()` to perform Firebase SDK-style calls. The array content will be synchronized with the changes you make through the ref.

To delete all elements, call `remove` on the ref itself:

```js
function removeAll(firebaseArray) {
  return firebaseArray.$ref().remove();
}
```

To remove a range, perform an `update` in which the keys to be removed are set to `null`:

```js
function removeRange(firebaseArray, start, end) {
  var keys = {};
  if (end === undefined) {
    end = firebaseArray.length;
  }
  for (var i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    keys[firebaseArray.$keyAt(i)] = null;
  }
  return firebaseArray.$ref().update(keys);
}
```

Both functions return promises.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the `firebaseArray.$ref().remove()` to work as the `remove()` function didn't exist on the object when ordered by child, but doing the following seemed to work though:

```
$firebaseUtils.doRemove(firebaseArray.$ref());
```